# using optional chaining in array of object and destructing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this

`const obj = [{a: 'a'}];`

I can get it like:
`const { a } = obj[0]; //a`

but what if obj['x'] doesn't exist?

I tried this with optional chainning but doesn't seem to work.
`const { a } = obj?.[1];`

Comment: As you're trying to destructure it, it still won't help (`obj?.[1]` returns just as `undefined` as `obj[1]` would), you should either drop the destructuring and use a simple property access (with `?.` where needed) or use destructuring everywhere with default values.

Comment: To add to @hgb123 answer. If you wan to use null as default value instead of undefined you can just use const {a = null} = obj?.[1] || {}.

Comment: @keysl will this worked the same? `const a = obj?.[1]?.a `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close to it. You should make sure to fallback with an empty object, for the destructing later to make sense

```js
const obj = [{a: 'a'}];
const { a } = obj?.[1] || {};

console.log(a)
```

***Update***

This would be even shorter if you don't use destructing in this case

```js
const obj = [{a: 'a'}];
const a = obj?.[1]?.a; // or: obj?.[1]?.['a']

console.log(a)
```

Comment: With `|| {}` there's no need for optional chaining o.O

Comment: @Andreas There is. Optional chaining is concerned with `obj` being undefined, OR operator is concerned what will be returned with `obj[1]` if `obj[1]` is undefined.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković _"but what if obj['x'] doesn't exist?"_ - So `obj` exists but `obj.x` may not. There's no need for optional chaining.

Comment: what if I avoid using destructing? `const a = obj?.[1]?.a`, do I still need a fallback?

Comment: @Andreas Except you will get a runtime error if you don't use optional chaining, and `obj` doesn't exist

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Why should there be a runtime error if an index is `undefined`? o.O -> https://jsfiddle.net/rupvesn9/

Comment: @JudyAllen when you don't use destructing in case like this `const a = obj?.[1]?.a`, there's no need to fallback

Comment: @Andreas It's not `index` that would be undefined, it's `obj`... Try this `obj?.[1] || {};` without optional chaining and `obj = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

```js
const { a } = obj[x] || {}
```

If `obj` does not have a property `x`, `a` will be set to `undefined`.

Comment: will this shorter? `const a = obj?.[1]?.a`

Answer (score 0):

You could festructure with an index as computed property and a default object for a missing item of the array.

```js
const
    obj = [{ a: 'a' }],
    { [2]: { a } = {} } = obj;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: omg this is so complicated, what if I use multiple `?` like `const a = obj?.[1]?.a`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following three cases, where I've used **optional chaining**.

You need to first check if the first element of the array (*index 0*) exists and then check if there's a field `a` in it.

```js
// Case 1:
const obj1 = [{ a: "a" }];
console.log(obj1?.[0]?.a); // "a"

// Case 2:
const obj2 = [{ b: "b" }];
console.log(obj2?.[0]?.a); // undefined

// Case 3:
const obj3 = [];
console.log(obj3?.[0]?.a); // undefined
```

Comment: @JudyAllen Please check if this solves your problem, let me know if you have any issues.